# SQL Server Migrations With Full Text Indexes

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, database-migration

We have a migration tool which runs through all the scripts that haven't been run on a customers database all within a transaction.  We were having a problem because of full text indexes where we cannot modify the full text indexes or any objects which they are created on be that tables or views as we cannot modify the full text index within a transaction.

We implemented a pre and post deployment script to drop and recreate the full text indexes but the issue we have now is that we cannot modify any procedures which make reference to CONTAINS OR FREETEXT as it errors with:

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'xx' 
because it is not full-text indexed.
```

We are really running out of ideas here so I was hoping others may have come across a solution as I assume there are many people running migrations in this style with a database with full text indexes.  The only solution I have at the moment is to run the migrations with no transaction which is very risky as if the migration fails will leave our database in a part migrated state.

The other option we have is to ditch full text indexing all together and look at something like Lucene.net but that presents other issues for us in regards to returning the right data for the right user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DDL transactional statements` are not standard across most relational databases.

**[Source](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL%3A_A_Competitive_Analysis)**

I'd recommend that you use transactions only for `DML` manipulation. SQL Server provides limited support for `DDL` statements in transactions, as you found out.

`DML (Data Manipulation Language)`

> Examples: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT statements

`DDL (Data Definition Language)`

> Examples: CREATE, ALTER, DROP statements